# Package a python project using batch scripts

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, batch-file, setuptools

Hi I currently have a python project that uses subprocess. Popen to run some batch files.

Is it possible to package the batch file as source. Thus, when some of our other python project use setup.py to include the current python project in install_requires, the other project could install and update those batch files and uses it from source (i.e. run these script with subprocess. Popen as well)?

Anyone have some idea how should I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: several batch files, that are reused in various python projects. we used to simply grab the batch files from svn/git when deploy the python projects. however, we are trying to figure out if there is a way that would allow us to work with the batch files same as working with python modules that we could specify in setup.py and setuptool could grab it for us.

Answer (score 0):

If you have bash scripts that are required to run your python package, you could simply store them within your package folder and they should be included when installing the package using setuptools. Here is an example of a possible folder structure:

```
/myproject
    /myproject
        __init__.py
        main.py
        batch.sh
    setup.py
```

In the main.py you could access the batch file by:

```
import os.path
import subprocess

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
batch_script = os.path.join(current_dir, 'batch.sh')
subprocess.call(batch_script)
```

**UPDATE**

Based on other comments, if you instead need a way to make batch scripts accessible to third party packages, you could specify the scripts in the 'scripts' key in setuptools. You can see this available option in setuptools [here](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#basic-use).